# Incorrect integer value: 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()[0]' for column 'po_trans_id' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

trying to insert multiple input and get the last id of other table and insert in into this table for foreign key.

tried to remove from the loop and tried to use foor loop

```
if($result){

     $j = 0;

    foreach($_POST as $val){
      $po_trans_id        = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()[$j]";
      $po_qty             = $_POST['po_qty'][$j];
      $po_unit            = $_POST['po_unit'][$j];
      $po_description     = $_POST['po_description'][$j];
      $po_unit_price      = $_POST['po_unit_price'][$j];
      $po_total_amount    = $_POST['po_total_amount'][$j];
      $payment_terms      = $_POST['paymentTerms'][$j];
      $user               = $_SESSION["username"][$j];
  $query = "INSERT INTO request_po (po_trans_id,po_qty,po_unit,po_description,po_unit_price,po_total_amount,totalPrice,user) VALUES ('$po_trans_id' , '$po_qty' , '$po_unit' , '$po_description' , '$po_unit_price' , '$po_total_amount' , '$totalPrice' , '$user')";
      $j++;
      $result = mysqli_multi_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
  }
```

id like to insert my last id to other table for relational database.

Comment: hi, this is for dev purpose only and trying to insert multiple row in a single click while getting the last id of the other table

Comment: Uhhh, everything is for "dev purpose". This is one of the recommendation how you can fix your code. It is a bug in your code!

Answer (score 1):

`LAST INSERT_ID()` is valid SQL. `LAST_INSERT_ID()[0]` is not, that's PHP notation and has no place in SQL.

What you want is available as [`insert_id`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) through `mysqli` itself. You *must* ensure that each command completed correctly before proceeding or you will potentially create a mess in your database that's difficult to unwind.

To fix this, keep in mind the following:

> **DO NOT** use `mysqli_multi_query`. This command does not support placeholders and cannot be secured properly.

What you want is to convert this to proper `mysqli` with prepared statements:

```
<?php
if ($result) {
  $j = 0;
  $count = count($_POST['po_qty']);

  // Use insert_id property
  $po_trans_id = $link->insert_id;

  $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO request_po (po_trans_id,po_qty,po_unit,po_description,po_unit_price,po_total_amount,totalPrice,user) VALUES (? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

  for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
    $stmt->bind_param('sssssss',
      $po_trans_id,
      $_POST['po_qty'][$j],
      $_POST['po_unit'][$j],
      $_POST['po_description'][$j],
      $_POST['po_unit_price'][$j],
      $_POST['po_total_amount'][$j],
      $_POST['paymentTerms'][$j],
      $_SESSION["username"][$j]
    );
    $stmt->execute();
  }
}
?>
```

Where that statement is prepared once and run many times. If you [enable exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) then you can avoid the `or die(...)` anti-pattern as well.

Comment: hi tadman, here's the error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myHome-IMS/PO-add.php:47 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myHome-IMS/PO-add.php on line 47"

Comment: i notice there's a spurios single quote at the end of the SQL text, right before the close paren. so the `prepare` failed with a syntax error, and returned FALSE. then the code tries to call `execute`of FALSE (a boolean object, rather than a MySQL statement;

Comment: @spencer7593 Good catch. I was trying to convert those to placeholders and missed that.

Comment: hi @tadman, after executing your code here's the error "mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 9 given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myHome-IMS/PO-add.php on line 55"

Comment: Was in a bit of a rush to adapt that code and made a mistake, using the more PDO style by accident, so I've corrected this with the right code. This is all covered [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) as well.

Comment: Hi, it has no error and my alert says its already inserted in database, and I've check the table and I think the data is not inserted.

Comment: hey! its already inserting but only in one row... I've inserted multiple data.

Comment: You may need to do additional debugging to get this to fully work, or frame whatever new problems you have in a new question.